# iPhone 5 Retina: Custom Email Templates Scrolling Horizontally (Display Bug)

Tags: iphone, css, html-email, iphone-5

I'm hand coding several email templates. They look great on iPhone 4/4S and desktop, but for some reason there is a horizontal scrolling that occurs on the iPhone 5 Retina. I'd like to avoid any horizontal scrolling.

I've looked at the source code of many other industry leading company email templates and find they don't suffer from the same issue, but there isn't really any uniform approach they're taking. Some use media queries, some don't.

The width of my templates is between 550px - 600px. Is there something I'm unaware of when it comes to retina and pixel density, and how that relates to tables?

**UPDATE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewHenderson/DvXa2/

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

<title>Test Template</title>

<style type="text/css">
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  table {
    width: 480px !important;
  }
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<table width="600" style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;background-color:#ffffff;color:#111;border-spacing:0;border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr>
  <td>
    <table width="600" style="border-spacing:0;border-collapse:collapse;">
      <tr>
        <td style="background-color:#eeeeee;"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table width="600" style="border-spacing:0;border-collapse:collapse;">
      <tr>
        <td style="background-color:#eeeeee;"></td>
        <td width="254" style="background-color:#EFEFE4;color:#9A3313;font-size:30px;vertical-align:middle;text-align:right;padding-top:9px;">
          <a href="http://placehold.it/165x31" style="border:0;"><img src="http://placehold.it/165x31" alt="Xxxxx" style="width:160px;min-height:31px;font-size:14pt;color:#9A3313;"></a>
        </td>
        <td width="334" style="background-color:#EFEFE4;color:#9A3313;font-size:28px;vertical-align:middle;padding:5px 0 0 10px;">
          Shopping Request
        </td>
        <td style="background-color:#eeeeee;"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table width="600" style="border-spacing:0;border-collapse:collapse;">
      <tr>
        <td style="background-color:#eeeeee;"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table width="600" style="border-spacing:0;border-collapse:collapse;">
      <tr>
        <td style="background-color:#eeeeee;"></td>
        <td width="144" style="vertical-align:top;padding:20px 0 0 15px;">
          <a href="${facebookProfileLink}">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/125" alt="" width="125"></a>
        </td>
        <td width="425" style="padding:20px 0 5px;line-height:22px;">
          <strong>I\'m looking for:</strong> ${product.name} <br>
          <strong>More about me:</strong>

          <ul style="list-style:disc;margin:5px 0 0;padding:15px;line-height:24px;">
            <li><strong>My Profile: </strong><a href="${facebookProfileLink}" style="color:#9A3313">facebook.com/${user.screenName}</a></li>
            <li><strong>Location:</strong> ${distance} miles from your store</li>
            <li><strong>Price Range:</strong> ${priceLevel}</li>
          </ul>

        </td>
        <td width="14"></td>
        <td style="background-color:#eeeeee;"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table width="600" style="border-spacing:0;border-collapse:collapse;">
      <tr>
        <td style="background-color:#eeeeee;"></td>
        <td width="159"></td>
        <td width="425" style="background:#eeeeee;"></td>
        <td width="14"></td>
        <td style="background-color:#eeeeee;"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table width="600" style="border-spacing:0;border-collapse:collapse;">
      <tr>
        <td style="background-color:#eeeeee;"></td>
        <td width="159"></td>
        <td width="425" style="padding:8px 0 30px;">
          To make a suggestion to ${user.firstName}, reply to this email with a picture and a short message. iPhone users, respond via the free&nbsp;<a href="#" style="color:#9A3313">Xxxxx app</a>.
        </td>
        <td width="14"></td>
        <td style="background-color:#eeeeee;"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table width="600" style="border-spacing:0;border-collapse:collapse;">
      <tr>
        <td style="background-color:#eeeeee;"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table width="600">
      <tr>
        <td style="font-size:85%;color:#555;width:580px;padding:5px 10px 0;">Sent via&nbsp;<a href="#" style="color:#9A3313">Xxxxx</a>, an exclusive service connecting shoppers with the best local stores.<br>
        To stop receiving these requests,&nbsp;<a href="#" style="color:#9A3313">click here</a>. 980 Xxxxx Street #X, San Francisco XXXXX</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I can update the question with more specifics if need be. Thanks!

Comment: Please post the code from your html email.

Comment: Added the code with Update.